# How to look up how permissions are grouped in Android 10

Tags: permissions, android-permissions, android-10.0

In Android 10, apps cannot look up how permissions are grouped in the UI.

ie:
`String group = pm.getPermissionInfo(permission, 0).group;`

group always equals android.permission-group.UNDEFINED.
How can I know the permission in which permission group.

Comment: Technically this is not possible. Android 10 and above versions SDK PermissionGroupInfo class not returning actual group name.